# How to handle required constructor parameters

Tags: model

Constructors in magento are a little ugly, required the values to be passed as array elements like this:

```
public function __construct($parameters) {
   $param = $parameters['param'];
}
```

additionally, to be safe this then becomes:

```
public function __construct($parameters) {
   if (isset($parameters['param'])) {
       $param = $parameters['param'];     
   }
}
```

Now that isnt ideal, but what about the situation where you could normally use typehinting to enforce a specific type:

```
public function __construct(MyObject $myObject) {
   $this->_myObject = $myObject;
}
```

how do you magento developers out there handle this?

```
public function __construct($parameters) {
   if (isset($parameters['myObject'])) {
       if ($parameters['myObject'] instanceof MyObject) {
           $this->_myObject = $myObject;
       } else {
           throw new InvalidArgumentException('myObject parameter was not an instance of MyObject');
       }
   }
}
```

this is very ugly but is there an alternative?

Keeping in mind that this is for only 1 single paramter!

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `instanceof` unless you are controlling application flow based on that value. To enforce constructor param conformity you would want to use type hinting (as you pointed out):

```
public function __construct(MyObject $myObject) {
   $this->_myObject = $myObject;
}
```

Multiple arguments are a tough nut to crack. My suggestion is that for each constructor param you have a matching validator and all constructor params must be of that validator type. For instance:

```
class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Validator_SalesOrder extends YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Validator
{
    public function __construct(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)
    {
        $this->_order = $order;
    }
}

class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Processor extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function __construct(array $params)
    {
        foreach($params as $param){
            if(!$param instanceof YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Validator){
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this is only an example - you could abstract away the constructor enforcement of the Validator class type to a parent class thus all subclasses would enforce the validator check.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a bit more context? Where/why can't you use the constructor with parameters? As for your last snippet, I'd shorten it with a tertiary operator:

```
$this->_myObject = (isset($param['myObject']) and 
    $param['myObject'] instanceof MyObject) ? $param['myObject'] : null;
```

Comment: You can use parameters but not if you also want to use the factory methods i.e. Mage::getModel(... which is where the parameters have to be passed as an array

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain why you want to use an array with fixed parameters?

If you are developing a custom model, you do not necessarily have to define a constructor which accepts an array as an argument. It's not obligatory. But if you really want to, consider using fixed setters which enforce types.

```
private $fixedParameter;

public function __construct(array $parameters) {
    $this->setFixedParameter($parameters['fixedParameter'];
}

public function setFixedParameter(FixedClass $fixedParameter) {
    $this->fixedParameter = $fixedParameter;
}
```